# Could $X^3 + X + 1$ have a root in $E?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the irreducible polynomial $g = X^4 + X + 1$ over $F_2$
and let $E$ be the extension of $F_2 =$ {0, 1} with a root $α$ of $g.$

Could $X^3 + X + 1$ have a root in $E?$

When working through this sheet Ive come across this question in which im not sure how to answer so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ‘No’.

If it had a root, say $\beta$, the field   $\mathbf F_2(\beta)$ would be a subfield of  $\mathbf F_2(\alpha)$.
This is impossible, since it would imply
$$4=[\mathbf F_2(\alpha)\colon\mathbf F_2]=[\mathbf F_2(\alpha)\colon\mathbf F_2(\beta)]\cdot[\mathbf F_2(\beta)\colon\mathbf F_2]=[\mathbf F_2(\alpha)\colon\mathbf F_2(\beta)]\cdot3.$$

There's a general theorem  which asserts that, given a prime $p$ and  natural numbers $r, s\ge1$,
$$\mathbf F_{p^r}\subset\mathbf F_{p^s}\iff r\mid s.$$